# Only one user cannot log into an app via Google ID Authentication

Tags: python, django, oauth

At work we run a python application where users log in via their google account.

One user gets an "Error logging in" message on any instance, this doesn't replicate on any other instance.

The app was made by a third party and they can't tell us why this happens. Is there a debugging tool or something that comes with Google auth that could be used to trace where the failure is happening?

Thanks in advance. If any more technical details are needed please let me know. I'm not very familiar with how all this works.

Comment: Hi, are u using oauth2? which library are u using to log in with google oauth2? python-social-auth? which scope do you require?

Comment: You should show at least any part of your code, to help us helping you. You could show the part of the code that returns the error "Error logging in" to understand what are you doing and what's happening, also a part of the template, view, API....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked this out. Whoever set up the user's ID originally had a capital letter in the ID - but not in the Email addr so this wasn't showing up anywhere.

Comment: The answer I provided below was correct then. Please accept my answer for the bounty.

Answer (score 2):

If it's only one user I'd say it's fairly safe to assume the problem has something to do with that user's credentials. It's hard to say without an error log but if it were me I'd first check to make sure the information the user is entering is the same as what oauth is expecting. Good luck and hope this helps!